# Is there a way in jquery to avoid having an expanding cell expand it's holding parent cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a homemade drop-down that, when clicked will show the more data below it.  Currently, when this happens it expands the holding cell to be taller.  Is there a way to avoid this and basically have it work like a normal drop down and write its data on top of the table.  An image has been included.

http://imageshack.com/a/img924/4021/dBkvyc.png

Image is at the link.  Couldn't get the image to upload.

Comment: `position:absolute` and z-index are your friends but beware of formatting after you do it. If you included your code here I could have given a more concrete answer.

Comment: The code is pretty complex and includes Tapestry (not my favorite framework).   I get your solution.  I've used those before.  So basically I'll position it absolute against the other div and z-index it above the current layer.

Comment: Make this an answer and I'll give you credit.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position:absolute` and `z-index` are your friends but beware of formatting after you do it.